# InfoPath 2013 development with error "Cannot start debugging. Pre-debugging negotiations with Host failed."

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, infopath, vsta

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (exclusively for InfoPath development, nothing else because of Microsoft) and Visual Studio 2013 for other development including SSRS, SSIS. I made a move to 2015 last week and that is where troubles came.

After installing VS2015 with SSTD update, I cannot debug or work on InfoPath form code any more. Everytime I try to debug or save the form with code, I get:

```
Cannot start debugging. Pre-debugging negotiations with Host failed.
```

I know this error is popular with SSIS rather than VSTA, **I couldn't find any post relate to this issue in VSTA in general and InfoPath in specific**. I have tried a lot of suggestion for the SSIS one when possible but nothing works.

I still need to do work on InfoPath 2013 form code (legacy project) and also have to use 2015, or 2017 for other projects. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

**Update:**

- Uninstall VS2012 and reinstall it doesn't help. Same with VSTA uninstalled and reinstalled. VS2015 is a big effort to uninstall so I leave it alone.
- Reinstalled Windows 10, InfoPath 2013, Visual Studio 2012 Update 5, VSTA 2012 then Visual Studio 2017 in exact order. Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only option is remove Visual Studio Tools for Application 2015 or later then reinstall/repair Visual Studio Tools for Application 2012. If you have to use VSTA 2015 for your SSIS or something else, you may need a separate machine.

I have reached MS but there is no response. I don't think this should be an answer for this issue but I would leave it here in case anyone needs help.

Comment: It worked. I had to remove the 2017 version and then repair the 2012 one. I agree that it doesn't seem like the best solution, but it works.